# page life expectancy and RAM usage

Tags: sql-server

I can't figure out why my page life expectancy avg is always lower than the recommanded value while my sql server instance has free RAM to use.
any idea on this?

Comment: Are you measuring based on some silly baseline like 300, which was relevant 80 years ago? Has it actually changed from your own baselines, or what the value was last week or last month? Are you having an actual performance problem? If so, what other metrics other than this largely meaningless number have you used to corroborate that there is a problem (never mind that page life expectancy is even part of the problem)?

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow. You might do better posting on [serverFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: @MikeW well let's make sure it's a good question before we just shovel it to another site.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't have the experience to judge whether this is a good question or not. It is, however, clearly off-topic for SO. I'd hope the folks at ServerFault would have the experience to judge the question on its merits and deal with it accordingly.

Comment: @MikeW well frankly if it belongs anywhere it's on dba.SE, not ServerFault. But this seems to be a point of confusion for a lot of folks - if you can't judge whether it is a good question, you shouldn't be voting to migrate it. What happens with bad questions that get migrated is far worse than bad questions that don't. Some background [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93440/recourse-for-bad-migrated-questions), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/provide-direct-feedback-for-rejected-migrations) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115716/165455).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the links. I'll take that on board. I can't change the vote, so that will have to stand for now.

Comment: @MikeW hit [close] again, and click Retract your vote.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes I'm using the 300 seconds value, how can I find out what the treshold should be for my system? My users are complaining about normal operations taking longer than usual to complete.

Comment: also I noticed that even when there's almost no workload on the server (only 1 active session), still my page life expectancy remains very low, often between 10s and 1.5 min.